# GridButtonColumn as a TargetControlID in ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit, radgrid, modalpopupextender

I have a GridButtonColumn in my RadGrid and I want to open a ModalPopupExtender on click event of the GridButtonColumn. Now the problem is what do I have to give in TargetControlID in my ModalPopupExtender?

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID=""
RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" PopupCo## Heading##ntrolID="TargetTemplatePanel" 
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ModalPopupExtender's TargetControlID to pretty much any server-side control you want.  Here's an example from a project of mine:

```
<div id="rscmain" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
</div>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE1" runat="server" TargetControlID="rscmain" />
```